# When dereferencing a vector to set a value the entire vector gets overwritten

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dereference

I am declaring a vector and a base element that essentially means the slot is open in my header file:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Map_Hash
{
private:
    vector<KeyValue<K,V>*> *hashTable;
    KeyValue<K,V> *baseElt;
}
```

I instantiate them in my constructor:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
Map_Hash<K,V>::Map_Hash(int M, K baseKey, V baseValue)
{
    this->M = M;
    baseElt = new KeyValue<K,V>(baseKey, baseValue);
    hashTable = new vector<KeyValue<K,V>*>(M, baseElt);
}
```

Now when I am trying to write new values to them I am doing it like this:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void Map_Hash<K,V>::add(K key)
{
    KeyValue<K,V> elt(key);
    int hashVal = getHashVal(elt);
    (*(*hashTable)[hashVal]) = elt;
}
```

There is a little more logic here to deal with the value already being in the table but I think it might just crowd up what is important. When the line `(*(*hashTable)[hashVal]) = elt;` is executed my entire vector is overwritten with the `elt` and all I want is just the index I have provided. Also what happens which I really cam't make sense of, but my `baseElt` also gets overwritten with this value. I'm sure it has something to do with how I am handling the pointers I am new to c++ so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You do not need pointers. Get rid of them.

Comment: Due to this statement `hashTable = new vector<KeyValue<K,V>*>(M, baseElt);` all the vector element are pointers and more specifically same pointers i.e baseElt. Therefore when you assign a value to any element at valid index of vector, then all the vector elements(pointers) will point to same value.

Comment: @sameerkn Consider posting it as answer because your comment is nearly an answer...

Comment: Just stop using pointer pointlessly. It complicates everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't use pointers.
- Don't use `new`.
- Use an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in your constructor.

Get rid of your pointers and make sure `M` and `baseElt` are before `hashTable`:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Map_Hash
{
private:
    int M;
    KeyValue<K,V> baseElt;
    vector<KeyValue<K,V>> hashTable;
}
```

Use an initializer list in your constructor:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
Map_Hash<K,V>::Map_Hash(int M, K baseKey, V baseValue) :
    M{ M },
    baseElt{ baseKey, baseValue },
    hashTable{ M, baseElt }
{
}
```

Then just add a new value to your vector:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void Map_Hash<K,V>::add(K key)
{
    KeyValue<K,V> elt{ key };
    int hashVal = getHashVal(elt);
    hashTable[hashVal] = elt;  // This will fail if hashVal is too big for the size of your vector!
}
```

You might want to rename `M`, that's a seriously bad name. I am also not sure why you'd want to construct your vector that way. Or use one at all when creating a hash map. There are already plenty of containers for storing keyvalues with hashing like `std::unordered_map` in the standard. All in all your [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Your question might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: specifically, `std::unordered_map::unordered_map(std::size_t)` initialises a hash map with a specified number of buckets

Comment: @max Vollmer thank you for the answer. I will definitely change this. I didn't know how to do this better and your solution is very elegant. Thank you again.